# Cordova InAppBrowser - How to disable URL and Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

i am currently working on a Hybrid app, for android and ios. Which uses a inappbrowser plugin with phonegap 3.0. I need to hide the url and navigation button. its working in ios  as per the post [Cordova InAppBrowser - How to disable URL and Navigation Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar)

How can i do the same for Android project

Thanks in Advance!
Arun Sathyan

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this in html page 
see this

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}
```

Comment: i'm using phonegap 3.0 with inappbrowser. I have already tried 'location=no' and its working only in ios, not in Android.

Comment: but this is command of html no effect is it on ios or in android

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but here this is handled by plugin right? Can we do anything on the plugin code just like i did in Xcode.

Comment: this is the cod ei tried var ref = window.open(encodeURI('PhoneAP.html'), '_blank', 'location=no');

Answer (score 0):

in config.xml file, make sure pattern of your URL matches in allow-intent tag.

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*" />
```