# Open external links in full screen from mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I'm building a Cordova app which has a link to an external site (https://www.example.com). I need the page to open in a full screen browser window(address bar hidden) on clicking a button in the app. Is there a way this can be done? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I've tried using the inAppBrowser but the reason it isn't working is because the external site that I'm opening requires a windows authentication. Because the inAppBrowser is the topmost view, the popup for the windows authentication doesn't show up and hence, I'm unable to view the page.

Comment: I dont think there is thing which will open a full screen webbrowser, You can you inAPP web browser for the purpose

Comment: Yes this can be done using `UIWebView` and presenting the corresponding page within a `UIView`. There are a number of ways this can be done. Additional information in your question will assist with a more detailed response.

Comment: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` just add (or change) the activity's android:theme attribute with given line in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I've added some edits to the question as to why the inAppBrowser cannot be used. Please have a look and suggest another method or a fix to the problem if possible.

Comment: @sud I tried your fix, but the browser still opens with the address bar

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/233) plugin, Then

ADD in the head

```
cordova.js
```

ADD a reference to YOUR `InAppBrowser.js` file

ADD links

```
onclick="var ref = window.open('LINK_HERE', '_self','location=no');
```

Comment: Hi, please refer to the edit that I've posted. I'd been trying to use the inappbrowser to fix this problem but it doesn't work because of the aforementioned reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,  it worked for me 
Step1: Add in app browser plugin as

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.2
```

step2: Add this code in your html page as

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;">
```

Comment: I tried this. But the problem is, is that my page has a windows authentication along with it. Whenever I try to use the inAppBrowser the popup for the login doesn't appear and it says "Failed to open document. You don't have access to the document". This is why I wanted the automatic full screen mode because it works perfectly if I open it in the system browser. But I need the address bar disabled or hidden.

Comment: If you want to disable the address bar you can you location=no

Comment: can you try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar) once