# Hide/Disable/Any other method to prevent user from typing in the address bar of the browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I'm building a Cordova app which opens an external link (https://www.example.com) in the system browser (Chrome or such). This page contains a frameset element that calls a javascript function on load to retrieve a document a display it it in one of the frames.
What I require is somehow to hide/disable the address bar of the browser so that people aren't able to navigate away from the page. I tried the FullScreen API but apparently you can't navigate while in fullscreen mode and I have actions buttons in that document. Is there any way to implement this?

PS, Yes, I have tried inAppBrowser. I know it's the easiest solution but the page that opens has an authentication popup that appears on load. And this doesn't work while I use the inAppBrowser.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar

Comment: Like I mentioned, inAppBrowser isn't working. That's why I need to open it in the system browser.
@tkay

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using an iframe, and changing the src of the iframe depending on which external link they need to use?

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
iframe.src ="https://www.example.com";
```