# URL show when load my Cordova app in android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, mobile-website

I am new Cordova web Developer. I created application according to following link.
[My reference link](https://zolmeister.com/2014/01/how-to-turn-webapp-into-native-android.html)
And I put my web Site link and load application from emulator.application load web browser and show link .

[image]

but I want show only page, without URL link.I refer following question and change my index file , build and reload project ,but still show url.

```
 window.open("http://18.16.253.15/", '_blank', 'toolbar=no')
```

expect some expert help. my cordova version is 5.4.1

[refer question this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used cordova for Ubuntu, but cordova for iOS and Android, and I'm a little bit confused about your image. You are calling an external url, right? What I see in your image is, that the page is opened in the standard browser of Ubuntu. In a standard browser it is normal, that the url is shown in the address field.

If you want to load an external url **inside** of your app, you should install the InAppBrowser, which you find here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

And follow the instruction there, it is working, I'm using it in every of my apps.

Comment: @Joerge Thanks , after I installed 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser' . every thing is ok.