# inAppBrowser Ios hide location URL

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have a scenario where I have to load an external URL within an App. I also want to come back to the App from the external browser.

```
`var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');`
```

I tried this and this is giving a DONE button, which brings me back to the App. However this shows the URL of the external page. I dont want the user to see the external URL. Is there any solution to this? Please help!

Comment: Does not `var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');` work for you because of inability to close the inappbrowser? `I also want to come back to the App from the external browser.` - I believe this is a separate question.

Comment: It works, but I want to have control on when the user can come back to the app rather than just pressing the back button in phone.Hence I need a button without the URL to be seen.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar. Also, by `control on when the user can come back to the app` do you mean disabling Back/Close button based on the external content?