# How to remove android navbar in cordova+cocoon

Tags: cordova, apache-cocoon

myBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://mysite.html','_blank','location=no','zoom=no','toolbar = no');

It only hide the address bar.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXk6a.png)

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar

Comment: thanks @nathanvda In the title I included cocoon which I cannot open the plugin inappbrowser.java file.