# On checking the internet availability, it navigates to the default browser(chrome) in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm trying to create a web app using phonegap. And I was using the code below and it worked fine.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {

                window.location.href = 'https://abc.xyz/';
            }
   </script>
```

Now I need to check my internet connectivity too, so as I used the above code with internet connection code but it navigates me to my default browser(chrome) on entering inside the application. Can any one help me with the solution. Here is the code below

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
             window.location.href = 'https://abc.xyz/';
                alert(" ready");
            }

            function onOnline() {
                alert("connected");
                window.location.href = 'https://abc.xyz/';
            }

            function onOffline() {
                debugger;
                console.log("lost connection");

                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Please Check your internet connection.', // message
                    null, // callback
                    'Sample', // title
                    'OK' // buttonName
                );
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **inappbrowser** Cordova Plugins:

> > [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)
>
> ```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
> ```

```
function onDeviceReady() {
                //onDeviceReaddy

                window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
                window.open('https://abc.xyz/', '_blank', 'location=yes,enableviewportscale=yes');
                }
```

It's load `https://abc.xyz/` this URL within the app.

Comment: @Jqa Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594139/cordova-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-navigation-bar

Comment: URL is displayed within the app on the top

Comment: Zoom in and Zoom out option is displayed by default in the app, I used the below line but I not getting it right, <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
 minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: Yes bro, here are the screenshots http://prntscr.com/ngla7k
http://prntscr.com/nglarm